# How to execute valuefirst API in ASP.NET MVC to send SMS

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SendOTP(string mob, string otp)
{            
    try
    {
        //ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11
               | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12
               | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
        string text = otp +" " + "is OTP for UNO MINDA Service App login";
        var client = new RestSharp.RestClient("https://api.myvfirst.com/psms/servlet/psms.Eservice2");
        client.Timeout = -1;
        client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("xyz", "XXXXXXX");
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);                
        var body = @"https://api.myvfirst.com/psms/servlet/psms.Eservice2?data=<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>"+@"<!DOCTYPE MESSAGE SYSTEM ""http://127.0.0.1:80/psms/dtd/messagev12.dtd"">"+@"<MESSAGE VER=""1.2"">"+@"<USER USERNAME=""xyz"" PASSWORD=""XXXXXX""/>"+   @"<SMS  UDH=""0"" CODING=""1"" TEXT=""" + text + @"""  PROPERTY=""0"" ID=""1"" TEMPLATEINFO="""" EMAILTEXT="""" ATTACHMENT="""">"+               @"<ADDRESS FROM=""MILPSD"" TO=""" + mob + @""" EMAIL="""" SEQ=""1"" TAG=""some clientside random data""/>"+@"</SMS>"+@"</MESSAGE>";
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        request.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
        request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Basic ZGVtb2ppdGVuZHJhOmppdGVuZHJhMTI=");
        
        request.AddParameter("application/xml",body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
        return Json(new { Message = "Otp Sent Successfully" });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

I am getting forbidden status in response, unable to send SMS. please help...

Comment: 1) Where are you getting the *forbidden status in response*?  Is your client getting this response when it tries to invoke your `SendOTP()` method?  Or is `SendOTP()` getting a forbidden status response internally when it makes its `client.Execute(request);` call?  2) If an exception is thrown, might you please [edit] your question to include the full `ToString()` output of the exception, including the exception type, message, traceback and inner exception(s), if any?

Comment: Are you aware we can decode your basic token? If that is a real password you might want to change it immediately and think of better ones in the future